# Hiding a specific cell hides random cells

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, cell, hidden

When I create my `UICollectionViewCells`, i tried in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
(if indexPath.row == 3){
    cell.hidden = YES;
}
```

I have about 6 cells. They're randomly set to `hidden` when i refresh my collectionview. Its not always only one cell that is hidden (even though i specifically hardcoded the `3` to make sure it would at least be one cell).

Any clue?

Comment: Add an else clause and set cell.hidden to NO - you are having a problem with cell reuse

Comment: Yep ,exactly that ! Thanks Paul, i wish you had written it as an answer so I could boost you up ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because cell was reused.
Always keep in mind, when you use `if` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you must always implement `else` part.

```
if (indexPath.row == 3){
    cell.hidden = YES;
} else {
    cell.hidden = NO;
}
```

or
`cell.hidden = indexPath.row == 3;`

Comment: Small edit there because you wrote "NO" twice but otherwise this is exactly that :)
Thank you ;)